# Whence the [language] and [languages] tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags, tagging

Generally, the Stack Exchange software prevents the creation of tags which differ in plurality. Either the tags [language](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/language) and [languages](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/languages) are old enough to predate that restriction, or someone with enough privileges overrode it. Neither tag has a wiki. What is their intended usage? Should they be merged?

Comment: [Relevant](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/376326).

Answer (score 7):

I can't see any good reason why either of these tags exists. As far as I'm concerned, they can be burninated.

Comment: There are probably few enough of them to edit manually. Most could also do with a bit of sprucing up while we're about it. I'll do a couple of the more egregious ones myself, but I don't yet have edit privileges on Server Fault, so I don't want to throw a pile into the review queues all at once.